# Performing A Computation When Two Values Are The Same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes `first` and `second`. For each `Second_ID` in `second`, I want to identify where in `first` the same ID is and then multiply the corresponding values. For example, `'Tony'`in `second` corresponds to a value of 4 and 11. `'Tony'` in `first` corresponds to a value of 20. I would like to somehow be able to multiply the the 4 and 11 by 20, and add the result as a new column to `second`.

In other words, I want to see where the ID in `second` matches the ID in `first`, multiply the two values, and add those new values as a column to the second dataframe. The entries in `first` are all unique, where as the entries in `second` are not necessarily unique.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'First_ID': ['Jill', 'John', 'Marc', 'Tony', 'Bob']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [6, 10, 0, 20, 100]})
first = pd.DataFrame.join(df1,df2)

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Second_ID': ['Jill', 'John', 'Tony', 'Bob', 'Tony']})
df5 = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [2, 3, 4, 5, 11]})
second = pd.DataFrame.join(df4,df5)

------------------
   First_ID Value
0   Jill    6
1   John    10
2   Marc    0
3   Tony    20
4   Bob     100



  Second_ID Value
0   Jill    2
1   John    3
2   Tony    4
3   Bob     5
4   Tony    11

Output:
  Second_ID Value NewVal
0   Jill    2       12
1   John    3       30
2   Tony    4       80
3   Bob     5       500
4   Tony    11      220
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
second['new_val'] = (second['Second_ID'].map(first.set_index('First_ID')['Value'])
                                        .fillna(1).mul(second['Value'])
                    )
```

Output:

```
  Second_ID  Value  new_val
0      Jill      2      2.0
1      John      3     30.0
2      Tony      4     80.0
3       Bob      5    500.0
4      Tony     11    220.0
```

Comment: Do you think you could provide a bit of an explanation as to how the code is working? I am trying to understand the map() function more but I don't fully understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Create key:value pair (dict) of first and map to second's  Second_ID and multiply with second's  Value

```
second['mult']=second['Value']*second['Second_ID'].map(dict(zip(first.First_ID,first.Value)))

    Second_ID  Value  mult
0      Jill      2    12
1      John      3    30
2      Tony      4    80
3       Bob      5   500
4      Tony     11   220
```